# Google app engine for php file upload

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am writing appcfg.py update command for uploading my file to google app engine for php but its not working . I get a invalid runtime or current user is not authorised error. Please help. My application is already whitelisted. Please explain step by step. Is there anything needed.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) SO isn't as usual forums are, and we prefer to help you by guiding you through your own research. So it would be helpfull for us if you could show us your current problematical code. So that we can reproduce it and help you with YOUR own work :)

Answer (score 0):

The user id that you are using has not been whitelisted to upload PHP apps.

It is no longer a requirement to have apps whitelisted but the user accounts still need to be whitelisted.